# Cross-Domain and ExtJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, cross-domain

Currently I'm stuck with a problem with the OPTIONS method type which I cannot change and ScriptTagProxy isn't working that well for me is there any way to set ExtJs.data.JsonStore
to open a proxy with POST method type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ScriptTagProxy](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy) is probably the only ExtJS provided solution you have to go cross domain.
You can configure your [JsonStore](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonStore) with a [ScriptTagProxy](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy) (via [JsonStore's](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonStore) proxy config attribute)

The best way forward would be to see why [ScriptTagProxy](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy) isn't working and fix it.